# How to show custom texonomy's category related post on single post page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I am working with a custom post type name= product and I have a custom taxonomy name= product-category
on the taxonomy-product.php I am showing a single product and related product based on its single product taxonomy term. But something is missing I can't figure it out.

here is my code.

```
<?php
                //related products
                $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'product-category', 'string');
                $term_ids = wp_list_pluck($terms,'term_id');

                  $second_query = new WP_Query( array(
                      'post_type' => 'products',
                      'tax_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'product-category',
                                        'field' => 'id',
                                        'terms' => $term_ids,
                                        'operator'=> 'AND' //Or 'AND' or 'NOT IN'
                                     )),
                      'posts_per_page' => 3,
                      'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                      'orderby' => 'rand',
                      'post__not_in'=>array($post->ID)
                   ) );
                      if($second_query->have_posts()) {
                         while ($second_query->have_posts() ) : $second_query->the_post(); ?>
                          <div class="single_related">
                               <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'related_sm', array('alt' => get_the_title()) ); ?> </a>
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                <?php } ?>
                           </div>
                       <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();
                       }?>
```

I have also tried
https://www.banna360.com/display-related-post-product-based-taxonomy-wordpress/

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/show-wordpress-related-posts-with-taxonomy-and-a-custom-post-type--cms-32303

Comment: I think you need to remove  'operator'=> 'AND'  from the tax_query. here AND means both the condition is true but you mentioned only one array in tax_query.

Comment: I tried In and NOT IN also but nothing happens

Comment: But you remove 'operator'=> 'AND' from the query. Bcz of on your mentioned URL also not used it.